# React Native Redux: props undefined

Tags: javascript, redux, react-native, react-native-ios

How to call a callback function? 
Or how to set state after mapStateToProps get data?

---

RegistrationContainers:

---

```
function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
  return {
     isRegistered: state.user.registered  // isRegistered: 1
  };


function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, props) {
  return {
     registration:(data) => dispatch(registration(data))
  };
```

---

RegistrationComponents:

---

```
onRegister(){
 let email = this.state.email;
 let password = this.state.password;
 let registerData = {email:email,password:password};

 registerData = JSON.stringify(registerData);

 this.props.registration(registerData)
 this.setState({isRegistered: this.props.isRegistered}) // isRegistered: undefined, but second run after is correct
```

---

registration actions:

---

```
export function OnRegistration(registered) {
/* ... */
return registered  }

export function registration(regData) {
return (dispatch) => {

    sendDataToApi(regData, "registration",(isRegistered)=>{
        dispatch({
            type: ON_REGISTRATION,
            registered: isRegistered
        })

    })
  }
}
```

---

registration reducer:

---

```
const initialState = {};
export function loginReducer(state = initialState, action) {
switch(action.type){
    case REGISTRATION:

        return Object.assign({},state,{
            registered: action.registered
        })
}

return state; }
```

Containers get current state, but containers props can't reach from components.

Comment: Can you post your `registration` action and reducer code?

Answer (score 0):

modify your methods by adding callback() functions. i.e.

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, props) {
  return {
     registration:(data, cb = null) => dispatch(registration(data, cb))
  };
```

and modify `registration(data)` method to:

```
registration(data, cb) {
 /* your code here */
 /* on successful registration, set user.registered to true in redux and 
  then call cb function */
 cb && cb();
}
```

modify `onRegister()` method to:

```
onRegister(){
 let email = this.state.email;
 let password = this.state.password;
 let registerData = {email:email,password:password};

 registerData = JSON.stringify(registerData);

 this.props.registration(registerData, () => {
     this.setState({isRegistered: this.props.isRegistered}) 
   }
 })
```